# How add lodash debounce to react input (func HandleChange)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, lodash

> import _, { debounce } from 'lodash';

Tell me how to use debounce lodash.
I want a call request two seconds after pressing a key

```
const handleChange = (event, onChange) => {
        try {
          const response = searchContractorsById(event.target.value);
          const { address, inn, orgName, ogrn, kpp, okpo, okved } = response;
          setContractors(true);
          console.log('response', response);
          toast.success('');
        } catch (error) {
          toast.error('');
        }
    
        onChange(event);
      };

 

    <Controller
                      name="inn"
                      control={control}
                      render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                        <TextField
                          value={value}
                          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, onChange)}
                          type="number"
                   
                        />
                      )}
                    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-leftpad-3vje2p?file=/src/InputText.jsx)

Component:

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";

var debounce = require("lodash.debounce");

function InputText({ defaultValue, label, placeholder, type, onChange }) {
  const debouncedChangeHandler = useMemo(() => {
    const changeHandler = (event) => {
      onChange(event);
    };

    return debounce(changeHandler, 2000);
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="form-group">
        {label && <label htmlFor="input-field">{label}</label>}
        <input
          className="form-input-text"
          type={type}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChange={debouncedChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default InputText;
```

Comment: I don't know how to use in my code

Comment: @АрамГаспарян Well, you got a working example now. I suggest you play around with the example and your own code and try to make it work. If there are issues that you cannot solve, you can ask a new question (or edit the current one) explaining what you have tried, what you think is happening and why it is not working and we will look at it again.